# When does a left Haar measure on a locally compact group restrict to a left Haar measure on a locally compact subgroup?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

Given a locally compact group which is not $\sigma$-compact, there exists a $\sigma$-compact subgroup $H$ of $G$ which is open and closed.

A Remark in Folland's, *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis*, Section $2.3$, claims the restriction of a left Haar measure $\lambda$ on $G$ results in a left Haar measure on $H$.

I haven't been able to come up with a proof of this fact.  For a general subgroup $H$ of $G$ this remark fails to be true, so how do the properties assigned to $H$ make this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work if the subgroup is *open*, so that it has positive measure.  (Open subgroups are automatically also closed.)  What problems have you had in the proof?  Surely it is easy to show that this restriction is left-invariant?

**added**
There would be a converse, too: a (measurable) subgroup with positive measure must be open.

Comment: It was a few weeks ago in a different context, so I don't remember.  I will try with your suggestion though, thanks!

Comment: Is it just this simple?  If $H$ is open, then all Borel subsets of $H$ consist of exactly the Borel subsets of $G$ which are contained in $H$?

Comment: You need to show $\mu$ is regular in order to show it is a Haar measure. But in fact in $\sigma$-compact groups every left invariant measure which is finite on compact sets and positive on open sets is regular, so (given this fact) this isn't hard.

Comment: @Cronus: The OP assumes $G$ NOT to be $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: But $H$ is, and we're trying to show the restriction of the Haar measure on $G$ to $H$ is a Haar measure. Since $H$ has the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra this is enough.

Comment: On the other hand, I am not sure at all what I said is true (that in $\sigma$-compact groups every left-invariant measure which is finite on compact sets and positive on open sets is Haar).

Comment: However, since the Haar measure on $G$ is regular and $H$ is open and has the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra, I don't think it should be hard to show the restriction to $H$ is also regular directly.